Statement on detectability based on relative height of abs max of spectrum
I have $2$ signals $s(t)$, $z(t)$ with the same energy $E(|s(t)|^2)=E(|z(t)|^2)=1$. However, the maxima of the signal spectra obtained with Fourier transforms verify: $\max(|S(f)|^2) \leq \max(|Z(f)|^2)$.
Can we say that the signal $s(t)$ will be harder to detect than $z(t)$? And why?

You can say anything you want, but a statement like this would need way more context to be meaningful. A simple example: you would get the lowest peak spectrum with a Dirac delta and that's quite easy to detect in the time domain.


Can we say that the signal s(t) will be harder to detect than z(t)?

No, we cannot say that. First of all, that makes unstated assumptions on "detection difficulty", we need to define that (with a metric on how to measure detection difficulty) before we can even ask this question. This would usually at the very least need definition of a noise model. What is easy to detect in additive Gaussian noise might be hard to detect in additive shot noise, or impossible to detect in multiplicative normal noise.
And secondly, it's really not true under any basic idea of detection that I could think of. Especially, the thing you think would be harder to detect seems to be more concentrated in time, so, in a purely power-based detection easier to notice; and any correlation detector, which would be the maximum-likelihood detector in uncorrelated additive noise, only cares about energy.
So, nope. Before you start stating what you mean with "harder to detect", both the statements "yes" nor "no" are equally wrong.

And why?

Incomplete questions don't allow for sensible answers.
